# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined at Websocket Angular JS"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I am pretty new to web technologies, I got bits & pieces of code from internet and somehow managed to form this code.

I have to get data to a web app developed in angularjs from websocket through APIs.

here is the code,

```
 angular.module("MyApp")
        .service("myService", function ($rootScope, $q) {
            return {
                _prevTransmittingStatus: null,
                transmitting: false,
                _transmissionStatus: function () {},
                socket: null,
                socket_msg_id: 0,
                socket_history: {},
                url: "ws://localhost:4848/app/",
                setOnTransmissionStatus: function (callback) {
                    var self = this;
                    this._transmissionStatus = function () {
                        if (self.transmitting != self._prevTransmittingStatus) {
                            self._prevTransmittingStatus = self.transmitting
                            callback(self.transmitting)
                        } else {}
                    }
                },

                connect: function (callback) {

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var promise = deferred.promise;

                    var self = this
                    this.transmitting = true;
                    this._transmissionStatus();
                    this.socket = new WebSocket(this.url);
                    this.socket.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
                        self.transmitting = false;
                        self._transmissionStatus();
                        deferred.resolve("connected")
                    });
                    this.socket.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                        var asJson = angular.fromJson(e.data)                   
                        var replyId = asJson.id;
                        var histItem = self.socket_history[replyId]
                        self.transmitting = false;
                        self._transmissionStatus();
                        if (angular.isUndefined(asJson.error)) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(histItem.defer.resolve(asJson.result)) 

                        } else {
                            **GetActiveDoc();/*how to call this */**
                            console.log("---rejected-----");
                            $rootScope.$apply(histItem.defer.reject(asJson.error)) 
                        }

                    });
                    return promise;
                },
                disconnect: function () {
                    this.socket.close();
                    this.transmitting = false;
                    this._transmissionStatus();
                    return this;
                },
                send: function (msg, scope, callback, onerror) {
                    console.info("SEND:", msg)
                    var _this = this;
                    this.transmitting = true;
                    this._transmissionStatus();
                    if (!this.socket) {
                        return this.connect().then(
                            function (histItem) {
                                console.log("CONNECT SUCCESS", histItem)


                            },
                            function (histItem) {
                                console.log("CONNECT ERROR", histItem)
                            }

                        ).then(function () {
                            return _this.send(msg, scope);
                        })
                    } else if (this.socket) {
                        console.log("socket is open")
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        var promise = deferred.promise;
                        msg.id = this.socket_msg_id;
                        this.socket_history[msg.id] = {
                            id: msg.id,
                            defer: deferred,
                            scope: scope,
                            msg: msg
                        };
                        this.socket_msg_id++
                        this.socket.send(angular.toJson(msg))
                        return promise
                    }
                },
                isConnected: function () {
                    return this.socket ? true : false;
                }
            }
        });
```

I am getting an error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined at Websocket"` only for the first time when I open my web app.
Can some one explain how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it myself,  just added/modified the code as follows,

```
 if(replyId >= 0){
       $rootScope.$apply(histItem.defer.resolve(asJson.result))                        
      }
```